# How can I loop through the first column of a PivotTable?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a PivotTable which has two source columns (Country, City) as its row fields.

[image: The part in red]

I want to iterate through each of the cells in the row field items (the part in red). I tried:

```
For Each pf In pvt.DataBodyRange.Columns
  MsgBox pf.Value
Next
```

but couldn't get those names.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like:

```
For Each pf In pvt.pivotfields("Country").DataRange
    MsgBox pf.Value
Next pf
```

Also using `MsgBox` Is going to create a load of pop ups. If you're just using this for debug consider using `Debug.Print` instead and watching in the Immediate Window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>) You won't have to keep dismissing the `MsgBox`

Update from Comment:

```
For Each pf in pvt.RowFields(1).DataRange
    Debug.Print pf.value
Next pf
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ^_^, but I want the country names as well as the city names...

Comment: @Amber Try the update. That will include city names as well.

Comment: I tried it but I got a 'Type Mismatch' error. on `For Each pf in pvt.RowFields(1).DataRange`

Comment: @Amber Works fine for me. What have you defined pvt as? Make sure it is defined to being just the pivot table i.e. `Sheet1.PivotTables(1)`

Comment: `Set pvt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).PivotTables(1)`. I can even get its name from `MsgBox pvt.Name`. I use Excel 2013. Could that be a problem?